# keras lstm(100) and lstm(units=100) produces different results?

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm

I am using keras 2.0.2 to create a lstm network for a classification task. The network topology is as below:

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(42)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(42)
import os
#os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'

model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)    
model.add(LSTM(units=100)) #line A
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

On the **same dataset**, with the current line A, I obtain a result as:

```
    precision    recall  f1  support
0   0.68    0.58    0.63    305
2   0.92    0.95    0.93    1520
avg 0.8 0.76    0.78    1825
```

, where 0, 2 indicate class labels

But when line A is changed to

```
model.add(LSTM(100))
```

I obtained different results:

```
    precision    recall  f1  support
0   0.66    0.58    0.62    305
2   0.92    0.94    0.93    1520
avg 0.79    0.76    0.77    1825
```

This does not make sense to me as according to the keras documentation https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm, I thought that the two lines should be same? Have I misunderstood anything?

Answer (score 5):

`model.add(LSTM(100))` and `model.add(LSTM(units=100))` are equivalent. What may cause the difference between the results is the randomness in the process. In order to avoid this randomness and get reproducible results, you should specify the seed in the beginning of your code.

For theano backend, add

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
```

to the top of your code.

For tensorflow backend, add

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)
```

to the top of your code.

The above code is taken from [this blog post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/).

Comment: I believed I have addressed this, see my updated code. but I still get this slightly different results

Comment: @Ziqi Are you using tensorflow backend? In this case you need to follow the second code snippet from my answer (that is, setting the seed with tf.set_random_seed as well).

Comment: I have already done this: tf.set_random_seed(42), unless the integer matters?

Comment: Try to change the order. First set numpy seed and then tensorflow seed. Does it still produce different results?

Comment: unfortunately not entirely. I ran with lstm(units=100) 3 times on the same dataset and there is +/- 1% in one or two of the figures (f1, p, r). I have updated my code as above

Comment: There are additional possible reasons for this difference. See the section "What if I Am Still Getting Different Results?" in the blog post that I linked to in my answer.